# update text in textarea on webpage using vba

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, vb6

please help me to write vba/vb6 code to update rich textbox

```
<textarea cols="60" rows="7" name="field_engagement_description[0][value]" 
id="edit-field-engagement-description-0-value" class="form-textarea"  
style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

I am using below code the same is not working

```
Set doc = IE.document

Set hcol = doc.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
For Each text In hcol
    If text.ID = "edit-field-engagement-description-0-value" Then
        text.Value = "NEW TEXT"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: HTML doesn't have a rich text box. If it's appearing as a "rich editor" then it's a client side script that is handling the rendering and updating, while storing (normally) HTML in the real (hidden) textarea control.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set doc = IE.document

doc.getElementById("edit-field-engagement-description-0-value").innerHTML = "New Text"
```

Comment: already tried using the above code but, that new text is get getting saved in innerhtml but not visible on the html page even after the submitting the page.
note: this is a rich textbox

Comment: You need to update a `textarea`'s content with `.value` rather than `.innerHTML`

Comment: Hi Alex,
tried that as well, but the same is not working