# VBA code to update textarea

Tags: vba, excel

I need to update a text area of an HTML page. I am using below code.

```
Set hcol = doc.getElementsByTagName("textarea")
    For Each txt In hcol
        If txt.Name = Module Then
            txt.innerText = Mark_Text
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value = "Done"
            Exit For
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value = "Module not found"
        End If
    Next
```

After the above code is successfully completed, I use below code to update the webpage.

```
Set hcol = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each inp In hcol
            If inp.Value = "Update Configuration" Then
                inp.Click
                Delay 3
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Once the update is done, when I go back to the webpage the text is not getting updated. Below is the view source details for the webpage

```
<td class="InputTitle" rowspan="3">Marketing Text</td>
<td class="InputCell" colspan="3" rowspan="3">
<textarea name="MarketingText;;1" id="MarketingText;;1" onfocus="workingText = this.value" 
  onblur="updateTextValue(this, &#39;MarketingText&#39;);" 
  style="font:normal 11px Arial;width:300px;" rows="4">
</textarea></td>
```

My problem seems to be similar to the one mentioned in the this link:
[please help me to write vba/vb6 code to update rich textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398036/update-text-in-textarea-on-webpage-using-vba)

I've already tried both the solutions provided in the above link but still it doesn't work.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the issue is with onfocus event not run when you set the value thru code.

can you add this code after setting the value

If txt.Name = Module Then

```
txt.innerText = Mark_Text
```

'add this part

```
txt.fireevent "Onfocus"
txt.fireevent "onblur"
```

Comment: That was so simple, I already tried `txt.fireevent "Onfocus"` but it didn't worked. But the `txt.fireevent "onblur"` worked perfectly. The text is now getting updated. Thanks a lot for your support.